# Trace inequality $tr(|XY|) \leq \|X\| tr(|Y|) $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, inequality, trace

Why does one have $tr(|XY|) \leq \|X\| tr(|Y|) $ for any complex matrices? I do know that Cauchy Schwarz establishes $|tr(X^*Y)|\leq \|X\| \|Y\|$.

Ok so far I have $\langle u,X^*Xu \rangle=\langle Xu,Xu \rangle \leq \|X^2\| \langle u,u \rangle $ hence $X^*X\leq \|X^2\|$. This implies $Y^*X^*XY \leq Y^*\|X^2\|Y$. Then we have $tr(Y^*X^*XY)\leq tr(Y^*\|X^2\|Y)$ by linearity we are then done.

Comment: What's the definition of $|A|$ for a matrix $A$?

Comment: You can use that $X^*X\leq \|X\|^2$.

Comment: @Roland $|A|=\sqrt{A^*A}$

Comment: @This is Me do you mean $tr(X^* X)=\|X\|^2$?

Comment: @Bennibenben No, I mean as in the partial ordering on positive matrices. But it does imply that $tr(Y^*X^*XY)\leq \|X\|^2 tr(Y^*Y)$.

Comment: so $X^*X \leq \|X\|^2 I$? Does $A\leq B$ imply $tr(A) \leq tr(B)$?

Comment: Yes to both questions!

Comment: @ this is me thanks :) I have updated my question

Comment: $A\leq B$ means $B-A\geq 0$. Now the trace is linear and the trace of a positive matrix is positive...

Comment: Stupid question I guess. Thanks problem is solved!

Comment: The proof in your question just gives the inequality for the squares of the arguments. To arrive at the original inequality, one still has to use that $0\leq A\leq B$ implies $A^{\frac 1 2}\leq B^{\frac 1 2}$ (note that this fact is non-trivial: for example, $0\leq A\leq B$ does not imply $A^2\leq B^2$).

Comment: @ maowao yes I would have to use that the square root is an operator monotone function thanks!